# Multiple & different Variables for loops BASH

Tags: linux, bash, loops, rhel, shift

I would like to run a for loop on a list of two columns, first column holds a name of a server, and the second column holds the UUID of the same server.

I would like to run the another loop on the same server name and UUID and only after this second loop completed I would like to return to the first loop but this time for the next server name & UUID.

All of these loops should be running only while a specifc condition occurs.

Any suggestions on how can I execute the following? I was thinking of doing it this way:

```
sudo ceph -s| grep 'osds: XX up' wc -l > ceph s
CEPH=(cat ceph s)
SERVER=(cat info/servernames)
UUID=(cat info/uuids)
AUTH= (cat info/token)
SPT=$(cat info/SPT)

while [ SCEPH -eq] 1 ]
do
set --$SERVER
for i in $UUID
do
## Poveroff #
echo "UUID: ${i}/powerState"
echo "TOKEN: ${AUTH}"
echo "name: $1"
echo "UUID: $1"
echo "SPT:$SPT"
sleep 2s


echo applying SPT
echo "TOKEN: $AUTH"
echo "NAME: $1"
echo "UUID:$i"


# shift
ping -c 1 "$1" >> /dev/null 2>&1
    if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
        shift
    else 
        echo "$1 is down"   ###should be the same sevrername echoed in the first loop###
    fi

sleep 2m
done
done
echo

#apply spt ## again spouse to run for the same servername and UUID ##
echo "APPLY SPTI
while [ $CEPH -eq 0 ]
do
set -- $SERYER
for
i in $UUID
    do
    echo "TOKEN: SAUTH"
    echo "NAME: $1"
    echo "UUID: Si"
shift
sleep 5s
done
done
```

example of UUID and server files

```
cat uuid
VDIVUIFDVNFDHYJ
VDIVUIFDVNFDTRE
VDIVUIFDVNFBVCN
VDIVUIFDVNFDNAQ
```

```
cat serversnames
SERVER1
SERVER2
SERVER3
SERVER4
```

that means, SERVER1 should be getting the UUID of the first line and so on.
Once all loops completed i want the next servername and uuid to run.

Any thoughts?

Comment: You should add a sample of the files that you're reading with `cat`.

Answer (score 1):

You could read the files in the same while loop using separate file descriptors.  The loop will stop when the shortest file is fully read:

```
#!/bin/bash

servernames="/tmp/info/servernames"
uuids="/tmp/info/uuids"


# using file descriptors
while IFS= read -r server && IFS= read -r uuid <&3; do

  echo "server: ${server} uuid: ${uuid}"

  # ping server

  # apply spti

done <${servernames} 3<${uuids}
```

Sample output:

```
server: SERVER1 uuid: VDIVUIFDVNFDHYJ
server: SERVER2 uuid: VDIVUIFDVNFDTRE
server: SERVER3 uuid: VDIVUIFDVNFBVCN
server: SERVER4 uuid: VDIVUIFDVNFDNAQ
```